# DataTables error 500 when waiting for large amount of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, datatables

I have a DataTable implementation with Knockout.JS and Knockout-mapper.js. I fetch my data with ajax call and it works nicely with say 5k records. But when i try to get say 100k records i get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Can anyone point me in right direction, how can i get large amount of data in my grid.

Page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
            function viewModel(data) {
                var self = this;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetRecordsJsonResultAll")", success: function (data) {
                    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(data));
                    $("#items").DataTable({
                        responsive: true
                    });

                }
            });
        });

</script>

<div class="row">
    <table id="items" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.Id"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.FirstName"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.LastName"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.Email"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Json results from controller (100k results)

```
public virtual JsonResult GetRecordsJsonResultAll()
    {
        var userBusinessLogic = InterfaceResolver.ResolveWithTransaction<IUserBusinessLogic>();
        var records = userBusinessLogic.GetAll().Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.FirstName,
            x.LastName,
            x.Email
        }).OrderBy(i => i.Id);

        var data = Json(new
        {
            max = records.Count(),
            items = records
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return data;
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: have you checked the json? It's possible there's a special character like an apostrophe / speechmark breaking the json that needs encoded and that's why there's an error rather than it being the number of results.

Comment: Yes i have JSON is fine. I have a same function that gets only 1000 results and it's working without problems.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs to determine the nature of the error. Error 500 means something has fallen over on the server side. Ideally you would need to have some form of logging, to identify issues exactly such as these (the one you are facing).

Comment: Tha't s the only error that i get. It takes some 20sec for database to return 100.000 results and i do get all items back, They are even sent to view but i think some sort of timeout is the problem.

Comment: which is the request limit size in your web.config, and how long do you stimate the json is?

Comment: Size limit is 100mb. Data i am receiving is 50mb

Comment: Where are you setting this size limit?

Comment: Web.config -  <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting your `MaxJsongLength` limit. Try changing your action method as

```
public virtual ActionResult GetRecordsJsonResultAll()
{
    var userBusinessLogic = InterfaceResolver.ResolveWithTransaction<IUserBusinessLogic>();
    var records = userBusinessLogic.GetAll().Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        x.FirstName,
        x.LastName,
        x.Email
    }).OrderBy(i => i.Id);

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

    var data = new
    {
        max = records.Count(),
        items = records
    };

    var result = new ContentResult
    {
        Content = serializer.Serialize(data),
        ContentType = "application/json"
    };
    return result;

}
```

Also, mapping `100000` records using knockout-mapping might result in slow/unresponsive user experience of webpage overall. Use pagination or load data on demand. You can test using

```
function viewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    console.log(data, "from server")
    self.items = data.items.slice(0,1000);
}
```